# How to add unique attribute in TR?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a form. After submission the data is sent to database.
I want to show all submissions details in dashboard  with dataTables.js, What how it looks like.

```
table = $('#entries').DataTable({
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        data: data_table,
        aoColumnDefs: [{ aTargets: -1, bSortable: false, bSearchable: false}],
        "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']],
        columns: Submissions.data_columns,
        createdRow:function(row,data,dataIndex){
            console.log(subId);
            for(i=0; i<subId.length; i++){ 
                $(row).attr("subId",subId[i]);
            }   
        }
});
```

subId is an array where i have submissions' Ids of the form. Is there a way that  I could use to add subId's to each row?

Comment: like `$(row).attr("subId", subId[dataIndex]);`?

Comment: couldn't find another way

Comment: every row has unique submission Id, and how can i give them that attribute? I have to take that attribute value when clicking

Comment: Where is the `subId` that you are referencing?

Comment: in this file. I did it thank You.  I didn't add unique subId attribute to each row. I save the subId's in array submissionsIds. and when clicking the row I take that row's rowIndex-1 like this. and after var currentSubId  = submissionsIds[rowIndex-1]